# htaccess - subdirectory as root, force https, non-www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, url-rewriting, subdirectory

The following rewrite rules work when i use them independently.  But together they ignore changing the root.  I want to:

1. force https
2. force non-www
3. have a subdirectory `/live` become the domain root

Server is like this:

```
/
/dev
/live
```

htaccess is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite /live to root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule !^live/ /live%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]

# Remove www + force https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This should happen:

```
http://example.com      -> https://example.com
http://www.example.com  -> https://example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com
```

But this happens:

```
http://example.com      -> https://example.com/live
http://www.example.com  -> https://example.com/live
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com/live
```

Would be great if anyone has a suggestion how this can use both rules, i don't want to have to move my site content into the root directory on my server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the order of your rules and simplify some minor things:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove www + force https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/live%{REQUEST_URI}/ -d
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NE,R=301]

# Rewrite /live to root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^live/ /live%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: This works great, i've noticed that it doesn't include anything inside of /live though.  e.g `example.com/subdirectory` ends up showing `example.com/live/subdirectory`.  Although if i include a trailing slash `example.com/subdirectory/` it will remain the same.  Any suggestions why this is, or how to avoid this when there's no trailing slash?

Comment: Tried with a clear cache.  Still showing `example.com/live/subdirectory/` in the address if i request `example.com/subdirectory`

Comment: This is working, but now relative paths are broken.  So `example.com/subdirectory` doesn't add the trailing slash and images/asset paths don't work.  But `example.com/subdirectory/` works great.

Comment: All paths are working now. Your last adjustment is the final answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
RewriteEngine on
#1)--http and www => https non-www--#
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,L]
#2)--rewrite root to /live--#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/live
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /live/$1 [NC,L]
```

The code above will first redirect :

- http://www.example.com

to

- https://example.com

and then rewrite

- https://example.com/

to

- https://example.com/live